# Annotation on a var in Trait gets not inherited in subclass

Tags: scala, annotations, traits

I have a trait with a var

```
trait Foo {
  @Id var _id: String
}
```

Now I want to initialize the var

```
class Bar(s: String) extends Foo {
  _id = s
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: class Bar needs to be abstract, since variable _id in class Foo of type String 
is not defined (Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined) class Bar(s: String) extends Foo {
```

The point is that the annotation is inherited when using a trait and I would like to use it.
I would like to have some traits with some annotations for mapping, and have them be available in a subclass.

Can someone provide an idea, hints, solution?

**Edit:**
I forgotted to write down the `extends Foo` in the example as noted in the comment. So the example was uncomplete.

**Edit:**
When I define the `var` in the Trait with `@Id var _id: String = _` then I can write in `Bar` simply `_id = s` and the annotation is properly inherited. But now it is not *forced* that the field must be set.

Comment: Note that in the example, `Bar` does not extend `Foo`, but in the error message it looks like it does. Is that a mistake in your example?

Comment: Yes the example was uncomplete.

Comment: I changed the title. Think this is more problem specific.

Answer (score 6):

`_id` is an abstract `var` in your trait `Foo`. Put `var` in front of it in class `Bar`:

```
class Bar(s: String) extends Foo {
  var _id = s
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the annotation gets not inherited. And I would like to have a way to _force_ the subclass to initialize the field.